# change vector values after declaring it inside a function

Tags: c++

I need to get the input two times, one to make n vectors (arr) and the other number for later use.

A function that takes the two integers goes into a loop for n times, each time the loop creates a vector.

When the loop ends, I can't access the vectors in any way. How can I save the vectors outside the loop?

stdin :

```
2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// Define introduction() here:
int intro(int num , int q  ) {
    std::cout << num <<q  << std::endl;
    for (int i =0; i < num; i++){
        int x=0;
        std::cin >> x;
        std::vector<int> arr(x);
        for (int i = 0; i<x; i++){
            std::cin >> arr[i];
            std::string list;
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        std::cout <<arr[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num =0;
    int q = 0;
    std::cin >> num >> q;
    // init two var. num and q
    std::cout << intro(num , q );
}
```

Comment: Read up on [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a std::vector of std::vectors in the enclosing scope to record all the data. Here's a truncated version of your code that demos this:

```
void intro(const int num) {
    //create a vector of vectors in the enclosing scope that will record
    //values entered in the inner for loops:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVectors {};
    for (int i =0; i < num; i++) {
        //create a vector in the inner for loop scope, but copy it into
        // myVectors (so it is accessible outside this scope)
        std::vector<int> temp {};
        myVectors.push_back(temp);
        //go ahead and load this vector with values:
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            myVectors[i].push_back(i * j);
       }
    }
    //now you can display the values
    for (auto vec : myVectors) {
        for (auto val: vec) {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Calling this function with num = 4, for example:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3
0 2 4 6
0 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `arr` declaration to outside the first `for` loop. This will keep it in [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) for the second

```
int intro(int num , int q  ) 
{
   std::cout << num <<q  << std::endl;

   std::vector<int> arr; // Vector here remains in scope
   for (int i =0; i < num; i++)
   {
           //std::vector<int> arr(x); // This vector will run out of scope after loop

           int x=0;
           std::cin >> x;
           for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
           {
               int newValue;
               std::cin >> newValue;
               arr.emplace_back(newValue); // Do emplace_back instead, benefit of vectors
               std::string list;
               std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
           }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
   {
       std::cout <<arr[i]<<std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt this function be declared as `void`?  
Or, better yet, facilitate the unused return value to return the vector `arr` and move the output loop out of the function. It does not really belong there, anyhow.